# Sending email from apex in sandbox

Tags: apex, email

I am sending email from apex  using salesforce sandbox. It is showing successfull but not getting delivered for any real email address, but it is working fine for temp mails.

It is only working for email addresses for temp mails not for real domain mails like google, hotmail, or any custom domain mail.

Working sample :-

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<String> to = new List<String>{'wovimov590@jobsfeel.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(to);
mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setSubject('Test Mail Subject');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Mail');
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
if(!results[0].isSuccess()){
    System.debug('Send Error: ' + results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
} else {
    System.debug('Email Send Successful!');
}
```

Not working sample :-

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<String> to = new List<String>{'sample.mail@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(to);
mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setSubject('Test Mail Subject');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Mail');
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
if(!results[0].isSuccess()){
    System.debug('Send Error: ' + results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
} else {
    System.debug('Email Send Successful!');
}
```

The only difference is in the email address.

Comment: None of the email addresses in your code are valid email addresses.  Please [edit] your post to include valid addresses and describe the specific results that you get.  Have you checked the spam folders of both inboxes?

Comment: Instead of second one, i've used my personal email address, but first email is from temp mail service.
I've checked spams as well, but it is only working for temp mail services not for actual domains.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also check the deliverability setting in the sandbox.

Comment: The code seems fine, perhaps check if there is a relay being used in the settings?
Setup > Email Deliverability Settings > Email Relay

Comment: Email Relay is set to "Prefered"